# Am I reading this stacktrace right?

Tags: java, android

Am i reading this stacktrace right:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
at xxx.MainController.gruppeSortieren(MainController.java:68)
at xxx.MainActivity$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:48)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:895)
at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:50)
at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:863)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My understanding:

1. I get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
2. this was caused while calling the `get` function of a `ArrayList`
3. this get was in the method `xxx.MainController.gruppeSortieren`

is this right? I need to find the bug and I'm not so familar with a stacktrace.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and the line number you should check is 68.  In addition, your `ArrayList` has a size of `1`, which means that only `get(0)` would not throw that exception, but you must have called `get(1)`.

Comment: You should be aware that Android sometimes gives you cascaded stack traces: you'll get a stack trace followed by 'Caused by:' and then another stack trace. The first one is frequently meaningless, and if you don't notice the second one it's possible to get very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here: xxx.MainController.gruppeSortieren(MainController.java:68)

Line 68 in MainController.java

The problem is that the Arraylist you created only has one object in it.
To access first index use: .get(0)

For all collection indexing starts from 0 till length-1

You must have tried to access index 1 using: .get(1)

And hence IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Yup, the first index in an array is 0.